# Don't strip the www from hyperlinks in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

When you write a URL in a comment on Stack Overflow it automatically gets formatted in blue and made into a hyperlink. If the subdomain "www" is present it is not shown in the link text, but remain part of the URL in the href.

As I just did [experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637137/how-to-restrict-openid-login-to-one-google-apps-domain-on-gae-again) this might cause some confusion for the unlucky person who does not realise that there might be a difference between the link URL and the shown URL. Not a big issue, but should probably be an easy fix. I know that some people prefer to remove the www for readability and I agree that that makes sense for a general newspaper or an ordinary blog, but for a technical Q&A like Stack Overflow the extra precision is IMHO needed.

Comment: I don't understand what the question you link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983934/how-limit-google-federated-login-to-specific-apps-domain) proves with regards to this "issue".

Comment: @balpha he want that when I write `http://www.facebook.com` it will show the link as `www.facebook.com` and not http://www.facebook.com (which indeed removes the `www`)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I know what he wants. I just don't understand why. And he says that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983934/how-limit-google-federated-login-to-specific-apps-domain is an example of the problem, which I don't understand how.

Comment: @balpha I think I see the point, sometimes having the `www` or not having it might be important, so hiding it is confusing. However IMO in such cases it should indeed be wrapped as inline code and the problem is solved. :)

Comment: You'd see less technical places such as newspapers and adverts insist on www. instead of the more technically minded, which usually just show the domain plain.

Comment: This is a tradeoff between readability and precision. This is of course only an issue as long as either the person writing the comment or the person reading the comment is not aware of this specific "www" stripping functionality.  If the functionality is changed I think readability will be maintained since most people do not write www anymore except when they have to.

Comment: I modified your title slightly to identify your issue more clearly. Subdomains do not get stripped, like in http://mail.google.com - **only** the "www" subdomain gets stripped.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're referring to the comments under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14637775/458741)?

I do not think this is necessary. Comments are not meant to be permanent and you shouldn't be putting important information into them if you can avoid it; that's what answers are for. I would edit that answer to include the additional information but I'm not 100% certain of whether that actually solved your issue?

Secondly, if you need to display the URL exactly, without making it clickable you can place it in back-ticks to display it exactly as required.

Comment: This issue is with commenting only since for questions only some urls are automatically translated into links. When it comes to your second point this is only an issue if either the person writing the comment or the person reading the comment is not aware of the www strip functionality

Comment: Is it @ArneS, the `www` is normally irrelevant. The fact that it's relevant in this situation means that the commenter should have paid more attention to what they were doing; either be using code mark-up, i.e. `www.google.com` or by editing their answer, if it was in fact an answer to the question.